# How do I make Visual Studio 2012 colors look like Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm not a fan of both the dark and light color themes offered in Visual Studio 2012.

How can I change colors of the title bar, menu bar, tool bars, etc to make them look like the ones in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I have the same feeling.. Better if someone answer this..

Comment: Join the club -> http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2819619-leave-vs-2010-theme-and-the-theme-editor-extensio

Comment: Looks like this guy's written a tool to change colors, so there's hope: http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/08/27/modify-visual-studio-2012-dark-and-light-themes.aspx (would probably take a log time to get it right though)

Comment: It has become a pain to locate files in solution explorer, or get a general idea of the folder structure of project

Comment: The new design is not as good as the previous. My main gripe is the way that everything floats on the page and blurs together... and I dislike the all caps headers OR SHOULD I SAY, I HATE THE ALL CAPS HEADERS.

Comment: @WillC: The ALL CAPS is optional. Quit VS2012, create this registry value (DWORD) and set its value to 1. On reboot, your menu will be cured:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\SuppressUppercaseConversion

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I had seen that it was possible to change it (and I probably will), but was making the point that we are used to seeing all caps as "yelling".

Comment: Turning the all caps off requires a reboot? This actually sounds like a joke that Mac/Linux users would make about MS tools.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The blue theme has been added back in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, no extensions required.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Download and install the [Color Theme Editor Extension 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) which works with VS2012.

(It allows you to apply a predefined theme or customise the theme for yourself - but you can choose the 'Blue' theme for a VS2010 style)

(edit: Or use the 'Blue' theme that is now built into VS2012 as of Update 2)

Answer (score 21):

I wrote [a blog post explaining in detail how to make VS 2012 look like VS 2010 as much as possible](http://www.not-implemented.com/make-visual-studio-2012-look-like-vs2010/). I will summarize it here.

- **Replace the new monochrome icons with the old ones** and **make the menu icons lowercase**.

  For this you need *both* the 2010 and 2012 versions installed and the [Visual Studio Icon Patcher](http://vsip.codeplex.com/) tool. Start the tool (it's a cmd line application) and enter `extract`, then `inject` and finally `menus`.
- **Change the color theme to blue**.

  Download the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05), go to "Tools - Customize Colors" and select the blue theme.
- **Final result**:

  [image]

  It is not exactly like VS2010 but it gets pretty damn close.

Comment: I am disappointed by the 'prerequisite of VS2010' for using icon patcher. I would use VS2010 if it's already installed on my machine.

Comment: @Flami:  If you have access to VS2010 (or know someone with it, or have access to install VS2010 Express on your machine), you can export the images and copy the files over to the machine you want to import them.